# How do I set an individual path variable for each user within the database?

Tags: php, database, path

Basically I want the users to upload files into their own individual folders within the server and then store the url/name of the file/folder into the database. I have already managed to upload files into one folder overall so what I need is to separate folders and locations according to the user

Comment: What have you tried? Can you elaborate on how the whole thing is set up? The user should log in via his browser and upload files to your server (and you store metadata in some DB which isn't really that much relevant), or did I get something wrong?

Comment: You can use sessions for that => http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a folder you can use the following code and store the same $structure ein the database

```
 <?php
    // Desired folder structure
    $structure = './depth1/$username';

    // To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
    // to mkdir() must be specified.

    if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
        die('Failed to create folders...');
    }

    // ...
    ?>
```

Comment: so by using the code the folder will not need to be created manually the system will do this?

Comment: @user3414573 Yes.The system creates the folder with required permission